Firedac not replacing images in firebird database
I am trying to replace images in a firebird database using Firedac and delphi 11.  All fields do get updated but the image fields IMAGE and IMGTHUMB do not change.
When adding new records the similar code works fine but I do need to replace some images with others and have no success so far.
The savetofile is primarily there for debugging to verify what I am trying to save and would probably be changed to savetostream later.
Some insights would be appreciated.
This same code works elsewhere when only a single image is replaced and not a batch.
      if SaveAction = 'UPDATE' then
      begin
//MUST DO AN UPDATE OF FIELDS AND ONLY if NECESSARY AN IMAGE
        SQLStr := 'UPDATE IMAGES SET';
        SQLStr := SQLStr +
        ' FORMNAME = ' + '''' + myImgObject.FormName + '''' +
        ', IMGTYPE = ' + '''' + inttostr(myImgObject.SpcPicInt) + '''' +
        ', IMGSOURCE = ' + '''' + myImgObject.ImgSource + '''' +
        ', IMGLABEL = ' + '''' + ImageLabel + '''' +
        ', IMGDESCR = ' + '''' + myImgObject.ImageDescr + '''' +
        ', IMGSCALE = ' + '''' + formatfloat('0.000', myImgObject.ImgScale) + '''' +
        ', IMGTITLE = ' + '''' + myImgObject.ImgTitle + '''' +
        ', IMGFILE = ' + '''' + theFilename + '''' +
        ', DATECHANGED = ' + '''' + MakeFireBirdDateTime(Now) + '''' +
        ', EDITOR = ' + '''' + '' + '''' +
        ' WHERE IMAGE_ID = ' + '''' + inttostr(ImageID) + '''';
        myQry.SQL.Add(SQLStr);
        try
          myQry.ExecSQL;
        except
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            ShowMessage('Exception class name = ' + E.ClassName);
            ShowMessage('Exception message = ' + E.Message);
            ShowMessage('DataInsert Error (Image)');
          end;
        end;

        if (myImgObject.ImgUpdate) AND (myImgObject.Bitmap.Width > 0) then
        begin
          with myQry do // Can also use the SQLDataset
          begin
            aBitmap := TBitmap.Create(10,10);
            aBitmap.Assign(myImgObject.Bitmap);
            CodecParams.Quality := 100;
            aBitmap.SaveToFile(ScratchPath + 'i1.jpg', @CodecParams);
            // Create a thumb
            ThumbW := 100;
            ThumbH := round(aBitmap.Height/aBitmap.Width) * ThumbW;
            ThumbBitmap := aBitmap.CreateThumbnail(ThumbW,ThumbH);
            ThumbBitmap.SaveToFile(ScratchPath + 'i2.jpg', @CodecParams);

            SQL.Clear;
            SQLStr := ('UPDATE IMAGES SET IMAGE = :IMAGE' + ', IMGTHUMB = :IMGTHUMB' +
              ' WHERE IMAGE_ID = ' + '''' + inttostr(myImgObject.ImgID) + '''');
            myQry.SQL.Add(SQLStr);
            Params[0].LoadFromFile(ScratchPath + 'i1.jpg', ftBlob);
            Params[1].LoadFromFile(ScratchPath + 'i2.jpg', ftBlob);
            try
              myQry.ExecSQL;
            except
              on E: Exception do
              begin
                ShowMessage('Exception class name = ' + E.ClassName);
                ShowMessage('Exception message = ' + E.Message);
                ShowMessage('DataInsert Error (Image)');
              end;
            end;
            myQry.close;
            aBitmap.Free;
            ThumbBitmap.free;
          end;
        end;

      end


Ad-hoc queries is an ugly mess and your one is especially strange. At least I see that you use different ImageID variables so you perhaps update different records in these pieces of code. Passing integer ID as a string literal also smells. Use debugger to find out what is happening in this code.

Thank you - this is the problem of copying code from one place to another - you noticed I used the incorrect ID in the second part.

Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use parameters instead of concatenating values into a query string.

Thank you Mark.  What is meant by SQL injection?

@BennieCoetzer See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, and https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection; I would recommend that you don't touch a database until you've learnt more about this.

Thanks - I have taken note.  As this is a local DB this is probably not a problem but I will consider this in future
